# Misconception regarding svelte transitions

Tags: javascript, svelte

I tried to use the help from this repl here (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/in-and-out) to make some divs fly in and fade out. Yet I think I have a little misunderstanding in my head...

I created a component that looks like this:

```
<script>
  import { fade, fly } from "svelte/transition";

  let steps = [
    { text: "these" },
    { text: "are" },
    { text: "the" },
    { text: "instructions" },
  ];

  function showNext() {
    if (currentStep === steps.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    currentStep++;
  }

  function showPrev() {
    if (currentStep === 0) {
      return;
    }
    currentStep--;
  }


</script>

<div
  class="h-36 flex items-center justify-center text-xl w-32 mx-auto"
  in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 2000 }}
  out:fade
>
  {steps[currentStep].text}
</div>

<button on:click={showPrev}>Back</button>
<button on:click={showNext}>Next</button>
```

And I'd like to fly in and fade out the `div` with the content each time the `Back`or `Next`Button is clicked. But it doesn't fly in neither fades out. I guess this is just because I'm changing the html content in the div right? If so, what would be a good option to fly in and fade out each of the objects in `steps` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions trigger on element creation/destruction. To make this work you can use [`{#key}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-key) around the element with the transition.

```html
{#key currentStep}
    <div
        class="h-36 flex items-center justify-center text-xl w-32 mx-auto"
        in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 2000 }}
        out:fade
    >
        {steps[currentStep].text}
    </div>
{/key}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/86a21a25fa7b46aeab5acb1ba4f1df32?version=3.49.0)

Note that during the transition both the old and new element exist and are part of the layout unless specified otherwise via styling. This results in layout shifts because by default twice the space is taken. You can apply additional styling to e.g. absolutely position the disappearing elements so they do not take up space.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! that's it:) I've never heared about the key-directive, but it's awesome:)

Comment: sorry, i totally forgot to mark it as you replied so quickly and it was already the perfect answer:)